# How to separate power supplies?

Tags: arduino, power-supply, mosfet, esp8266

The following schema shows a measuring lithium ion battery device.

The terminals "Power Supply" provides 4.2V and enough amps (LabSupply). The terminals "Battery" and "Resistor" connects the named devices.
Solution intend of the circuit:

- uC (ESP12F) should control via Q2 PMOS (to isolate the battery from power source) the charging of the LiIon battery at the battery terminal up the 4.2V. Sensing of the battery voltage is done by the voltage divider R4/R5 connected to the 1V ADC of the ESP12F
- the U14 (INA219) is measuring the current while the battery is charging. Vin+/Vin- are connected via a 0.1O Ohm resistor and the voltage drop is sensored by the INA219 and provided by I2C protocol to the uC.
- uC should control via Q1 (NMOS) the discharing of the battery via a known 1 Ohm power resistor by connecting the resistor to the GND.
- When power source is switched off, the battery's charge should stay.

Symptom: the battery is discharged by a 80mA current if power source is turned off. uC is still work which isn't wanted. ESP12Fs normally draw 80mA in WiFi mode. I also see the LM working and providing 3.3V.

My Problem:

When the "Power Supply" is off, the circuit still draws power from the battery which for understandable reason I don't want. How do I prevent the malicious powering of the voltage regulator from source to drain the Q2 ??

What do I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: what's wrong? No explanation what you're trying to do, no hints how much power you expect to be drawn from the battery or how much you're measuring. R4/R5 will draw some, for a start. Does that explain your observation? Why is Q2 wired to drain the battery via its body diode?

Comment: @user_1818839: The problem is, that the circuit does not protect the battery from draining out when the power is of. I expected that the uC is down when the power supply is off but the battery is still attached to its terminal. LiIon should not be discharged below 2.5V as I understood. R4/R5 are a voltage divider for the uC ADC sensor. What I learned from your comment that I need much higher resistors for R4/R5. But how to prevent the flow from the battery over Q2 back to U2 which powers the uC?

Comment: You still haven't added your current drain measurements to the question. If Q2 was the other way round, at least its body diode wouldn't conduct to discharge the battery. But what you intend it to do isn't clear enough for me to call that a solution. One approach to battery isolation involves 2 PMOS transistors, with their sources connected, so with both off, neither body diode conducts.

Comment: Hi @user_1818839, I update the initial problem description. I think now it should become clearer. Thanks for you head-up.

Answer (score 1):

The schematic looks great and is a big help, thanks for posting it. In your circuit R5 and R5 will always drain your battery at the rate of about 0.12 milliamps. Q2 puts + into the - terminal of  U14.  These are the major sources of undesirable current drain.

Comment: I understood that I need to increase R4/R5. U14 is a current sensor (INA219) and Vin+ /Vin- are the current sensor terminals connected by 0.1Ohm. How do I prevent that the current flows back over Q2 to the voltage regulator powering the uC. The battery charging should be controlled by Q2 but it should not allow discharging.

Comment: Found two other flaws in the design. 1.) Between Battery1 Terminal and Q2 I placed a Schottky diode and there is no back flow from the battery to thru the Q2. 2.) the Vgs is not big enough. The P-Mosfet closes but it doesn't switch thru.